# Batch rename files with regex

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-rename

I have a number of files with the following format:

> *name*_*name<number><number>*[TIF<11 numbers>].jpg

e.g. `john_sam01 [TIF 15355474840].jpg`

And I would like to remove the `[TIF 15355474840]` from all of these files
This includes a leading space before the *'[TIF...'* and a different combination of 11 numbers each time.

So the previous example would become:
`josh_sam01.jpg`

---

In short, using powershell (or cmd.exe) with regex I would like to turn this filename:

> josh_sam01 [TIF 15355474840].jpg

Into this:

> josh_sam01.jpg

With variables being: 'john' 'sam' two numbers and the numbers after TIF.

Answer (score 2):

Something like, with added newlines for clarity:

```
dir ‹parameters to select the set of files› |
   % {
     $newName = $_.Name -replace '\s\[TIF \d+\]',''
     rename-item -newname $newName -literalPath $_.Fullname
   }
```

Almost certainly adding -`whatif` to the rename until I was sure I had the file selection and rename correct.

Comment: I'd probably do `-ireplace`, you just never know :)

Comment: `Rename-Item` can read directly from the pipeline. Just build the new name in a scriptblock: `... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\s\[TIF \d+\]' }`

Comment: @Kev - In PowerShell `-replace` is case-insensitive, so it's the same as `-ireplace`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf all these years using PowerShell and I never noticed :)

Comment: @Kev - it happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence I'm new to powershell, but what do you mean by ‹parameters to select the set of files›? @Richard

Comment: @joe_young whatever you need to select your files to be renamed. (Eg. `-recurse` if files are across multiple folders.)